# Python Sorting Dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

If i have a dictionary that has two values per entry in a tuple 
eg . 
(jon, 100)
(ellie, 200)
(mati, 120)
(steve, 250)
 I want to order them in order of their score (second value). But then i only want to display the names. 
eg : steve, ellie, mati , jon
how would i go about it?

```
f = open('data.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
new_dict = {}

for row in reader:
    new_dict[row[0]] = random.gauss(float(row[1]), float(row[2]))

order_list = sorted(new_dict, key = new_dict[row[0]], reverse = False)
return order_list
```

so far i got this and i also get errors like

```
"order_list = sorted(new_dict, key = new_dict[row[0]], reverse = False)"
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

any help would be grand.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort dictionary"? Do you mean something as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)?

Comment: The key needs to be a function

Answer (score 0):

First sort the values with a key function that gets the score only, and then get the first item of the pairs from the sorted data.

```
from operator import itemgetter
order_list = [e[0] for e in sorted(new_dict.values(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]
```

The `reverse=True` is because you wanted the highest-scoring name first, so it's a descending sort instead of the default ascending.

That `itemgetter(1)` function is equivalent to `lambda e: e[1]`, which would also work.

```
order_list = [e[0] for e in sorted(new_dict.values(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)]
```

If `itemgetter(1)` seems like a long-winded way to make a simple lambda, note that you could have instead used `from operator import itemgetter as ig` and then written `key=ig(1)`

Comment: Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the operand’s __getitem__() method. If multiple items are specified, returns a tuple of lookup values.

Comment: Note also that `e[1]` is equivalent to `e.__getitem__(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'ellie': 200, 'jon': 100, 'mati': 120, 'steve': 250}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k])
['jon', 'mati', 'ellie', 'steve']
```

`sorted` treats the dictionary as an iterator, and retrieves the keys of the dictionary.

The `key` parameter must be a function (in this case an unnamed function, a `lambda`) that returns a sorting key for the current value being sorted.

Comment: That's not the data structure described though. Where's the "two values per entry in a tuple"?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```
    import pandas as pd

    def names_ordered_by_score(file_name):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, names=['name', 'score'])
        df.sort_values(by='score', inplace=True)
        return df.name.values.tolist()

    names_ordered_by_score('data.csv')
```

This is a hard-coded test.

```
    import pandas as pd

    def names_ordered_by_score():
        df = pd.DataFrame([('jon', 100), 
                           ('ellie', 200), 
                           ('mati', 120)], 
                          columns=['name', 'score'])
        df.sort_values(by='score', inplace=True)
        return df.name.values.tolist()

    names_ordered_by_score()
```

Comment: The OP didn't indicate that they're using Pandas. This is a rather heavy library to import for this task.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it. This can be done in one line. A beginner shouldn't start using heavyweight data processing libraries like pandas before understanding the batteries-included basics.